# Policy error while trying to use SNS via Aws Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function which when triggered, sends an SNS. However, on testing the lambda function, it says that I have not enabled sns:Publish policy and gives me the following error.

```
     "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AuthorizationError) when calling the Publish operation: User: arn:aws:sts::466331843672:assumed-role/pill_dispense-role-57u2gjjb/pill_dispense is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:466331843672:smart_pill_sns because no identity-based policy allows the SNS:Publish action",
  "errorType": "AuthorizationErrorException",
  "requestId": "11a58023-8c8d-4942-ad88-1f8a12b0c0d6",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 19, in lambda_handler\n    response = sns.publish(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
```

So I went back to the user and attached an inline policy as follows :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:466331843672:smart_pill_sns"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish",
                "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:AddPermission",
                "SNS:RemovePermission",
                "SNS:DeleteTopic",
                "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "SNS:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

After saving the policy , I still get the same error when i test my lambda function. Please help

Comment: *"So I went back to the user"*, there should be not users involved here at all, only roles. You probably attached it to to the wrong IAM entity.

Comment: @luk2302 Am i not supposed to attach the policy to the IAM user which I use? should i only create roles ?

Comment: add `sns:publish` to your lambda execution role.

Comment: It's the [Lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) that needs this permission.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding:

```
"Action": "sns:Publish"
```

to the IAM Role `BasicLambdaExecutionRole` (*not* to an IAM User).